# Sending Multiple Commands in TCPClient

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I am trying to use

```
private TcpClient tcpClient;
```

in a class and every time when I send a command like `LIST`, `RETR`, `STOR`, I used to lock the TCPClient for that particular time of execution of commands and getting response.

Now when I send the other command in between the one is executing, It isn't able to lock that tcpclient instance again.

How should I send the other command when one is executing. For all commands I need to lock the TCPClient, that I can't change.

Answer (score 2):

This is a design problem. You need to design a multithreaded way of accessing the TcpClient without locking it excessivly

May i suggest you use a queue instead of locking the TcpClient ? I reckon your trying to build an FTP client. (i am guessing based on the LIST, RETR and STOR commands).

An example of a simple queue

```
private TcpClient client;
private Queue<string> commands = new Queue<string>();
private AutoResetEvent resume = new AutoResetEvent(false);

public void Add(string cmd)
{
  lock(commands) { commands.Enqueue(cmd); }
  resume.Set();

}

private void ThreadRun() // this method runs on a different thread
{
   while(!quit.WaitOne(0,true))
   {
      resume.WaitOne();
      string command;
      lock(commands) { command = commands.Dequeue(); }
      Process(command);

   }


}
```

You should refrain from trying to "lock" objects just to get it thread-safe. A thread-safe application is designed to operate with minimal locking, rather than forcing locks to enforce thread safety.

Comment: it means when One command is fully executed then only again second command will execute. That's what I don't want, I want to execute the threads independently, but due to locking of TCPClient, I can't run the different threads.

Comment: The problem is not with locking of the TCP client. The problem is that you have a single TCP client that is maintaining a single connection to a server. If you want multiple commands at once, have multiple TCP clients, so you can have multiple conversations going on at once.

Comment: @Yuliy: Poor design choice to use multiple clients just to be able to send several commands.

Answer (score 0):

Use one TcpClient for each thread.

Comment: is it a good way opening more than one tcpclient??If the app connects to a data server and also listens to incoming messages over it???

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Locking is all bad when it comes to socket programming. @AndrewKeith's solution is quite good for queuing commands and to send them.

What you need is to have a request id that you can put in another queue and send it back with the response. You can have several ongoing commands by doing so.

Simple pseudo code:

```
public void Send(ICommand command)
{
    var myPacket = new CommandPacket {
        Command = command,
        RequestId = Guid.NewGuid()
    };
    _pendingCommands.Add(myPacket);

    var buffer = Serialize(myPacket);
    socket.Send(buffer);
}

public void OnReceive(IAsynResult ar)
{
    var bytesRead =  socket.EndRecieve(ar);
    _inStream.Write(_readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

    if (GotCompletedPacket(_inStream))
    {
        var packet = Deserialize(_inStream);
        var waitingCommand = _pendingCommands.FirstOrDefault(p => p.RequestId == packet.RequestId);

        if (waitingCommand != null)
          //got a reply to the command.
    }

}
```

I would personally add a delegate when invoking the command:

```
public void Send(ICommand command, ICommandHandler handler)
```

and invoke that handler when a reply have been received.